# Is ScenarioContext.Current thread safe?

Tags: c#, concurrency, bdd, specflow

I get the impression that it's not. I have three integration tests that succeed when run individually, but when run in parallel, I get `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.`

I was sure hoping that `ScenarioContext.Current` always referred to the correct scenario, but it seems it's getting confused. Has anyone successfully added thread safety to this class? Or is there another approach I should be using for sharing values among step files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScenarioContext.Curent source:

```
public static ScenarioContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Accessing NULL ScenarioContext");
            }
            return current;
        }
        internal set { current = value; }
    }
```

As you can see, it is not threadsafe 
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Runtime/ScenarioContext.cs

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a better way to share values while running tests in parallel? I think using `FeatureContext` and context injection might solve some of my concurrency problems, but then sharing between bindings still becomes an issue, especially when a step binding is more generic and isn't related to any specific feature.

Comment: FeatureContext and ScenarioContext can both be injected using context injection

Comment: @Andrew I think ScenarioContext.cs has moved to: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioContext.cs

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be handled more nicely in SpecFlow V2: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/

Extract (simpler of the options):

```
[Binding]
public class StepsWithScenarioContext : Steps
{
    [Given(@"I put something into the context")]
    public void GivenIPutSomethingIntoTheContext()
    {
        this.ScenarioContext.Set("test-value", "test-key");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but it's whell referenced, so this is my solution :

Just replace the ScenarioContext by a custom implementation like this :

```
 public class ScenarioContextSafe
{
    private static ScenarioContextSafe _current;
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();
    public static ScenarioContextSafe Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Locker) {
                return _current ?? (_current = new ScenarioContextSafe());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        lock (Locker) {                
            _current = null;
        }
    }

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        _concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);            
    }

    public void Set(object value, string key)
    {
        if (!_concurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            _concurrentDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
        else 
            _concurrentDictionary[key] = value;            
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        object result;
        _concurrentDictionary.TryRemove(key, out result);
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object result;
        _concurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result);
        return (T)result;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _concurrentDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void Pending()
    {
        ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();            
    }

    public ScenarioInfo ScenarioInfo{
        get { return ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo; }
    }
}
```

Then, create a hook for reset the context before each scenario

```
 [BeforeScenario()]
    public static void BeforeAllScenario()
    {
        ScenarioContextSafe.Reset();
    }
```

I hope this help someone.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem because there is still only one "Current", but you need one for each thread. Use something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx